# How do I use an existing hashed integer to index a hash table?

Tags: c++, boost, hash, unordered-map, crc32

I'm using Boost for C++ at the moment, and am trying to implement the unordered map (aka hash table) using CRC32. To my knowledge it will take a string as an initial key, hash it, and apply another operation so that it will fit into the number of buckets.

Though in my situation, I would like to hash the string key beforehand (using a separate CRC function in Boost), then use that ID to index the table. The problem that I need help with is that a CRC32 hash has 2^32 potential values, and I doubt I'll ever need a table with 2^32 elements. What should I do in this situation?

Thanks for any help here!

Comment: Boost already contains multiple unordered_map implementations, why are you writing one from scratch?

Comment: This is why the container will hash it again to fit inside the bucket space.  Do you have a good reason to do this?  Using a hash for error correction vs. for bucketing are two different uses...

Comment: Well I'm using the hash table in the debug build only, its supposed to retain the corresponding string IDs as game entity names. But in the release build I only want the IDs, since my game engine should only ever use those. That's my main motivation to using a separate hash function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the modulus operator -- `%` in the C-based languages:

```
int hashtableIndex = hashValue % hashtableSize;
```

But note that the sign of the result, in C++, is "implementation defined", and can be negative if hashValue is negative.  So one may want to turn off the sign bit in hashValue before doing the `%` operation.

Also note that, if `hashtableSize` is known to be a power of two, one can simply mask `hashValue` to get the index:

```
int hashtableIndex = hashValue & (hashtableSize - 1);
```

Comment: If `hashtableSize` is of unsigned type, there will be no problems with sign

Comment: Good ideas. But say I have 7 buckets/elements. If I were to use a modulus for that, then wouldn't the collision probability grow from 1/2^32 to 1/7? In that case would masking the hash value be more beneficial?

Comment: The collision probability for a 7 bucket table is always going to be (ideally) 1 in 7.  And masking is just another way to do modulus -- exactly equivalent mathematically (aside from sign issues) -- but it only works for powers of two.

Comment: @anatolyg -- ["the binary % operator yields the remainder from the division of the first expression by the second. .... If both operands are nonnegative then the remainder is nonnegative; if not, the sign of the remainder is implementation-defined".](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#cite_note-0).

Comment: Alright, I also remember researching that was one weakness with smaller hash tables. Marked as answer.

Comment: Note that even though you "narrow" the hash value to select a table slot, you can still stick the full hash value into your hash entries, to provide for a quick comparison.  Only if the hash value matches the search hash value do you do the "long" compare of the "real" key value.  This makes it efficient to put the "real" key value (eg, a string) in a separate location, possibly "shared" with some larger structure.

Comment: Sorry but doesn't makes sense to have an hashtable that is a power of two in size, for best performances and less collisions, an hashtable should be a prime number in size.

Comment: There is a slight advantage in using a prime number if your hash value is not particularly randomly distributed (and this used to be the tradition).  But most "good" hash algorithms produce randomly distributed values such that there would be no advantage to a prime size.